One-minute wait time before file is downloaded from repo1.maven.org (behind corporate proxy)
We're using Nexus as an artifact repository/proxy in our organisation's network, behind a corporate firewall. Recently, we started to notice issues where files would not or only partially be downloaded.
Looking into it we whittled the problem down to some weird wait time before the actual download. The wait time is exactly one minute before the download starts.
The curl trace below shows the verbose logs. We tried with loads of different packages, it's not this particular file. After the "Request completely sent off", the connection seems to stall for one minute.
We have tried the same command from elsewhere (no proxy), and as expected download starts immediately. We are not responsible for the proxy, but are trying to provide pointers to help resolve the issue.
For what it's worth, the proxy is a Forcepoint (previously Websense) proxy, anonymized below.
What could be the issue? What else could we try to get to the bottom of this?
C:\>curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/25.1-android/guava-25.1-android.jar -x http://our-proxy.xx.xx:443 -v -k --output c:\temp\mavenJAR.jar
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Host our-proxy.xx.xx:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 192.168.32.25
*   Trying 192.168.32.25:443...
* Connected to our-proxy.xx.xx (192.168.32.25) port 443
* CONNECT tunnel: HTTP/1.1 negotiated
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to repo1.maven.org:443
> CONNECT repo1.maven.org:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: repo1.maven.org:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.8.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< Date: Fri, 11 Oct 2024 15:32:45 GMT
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Via: 1.1 PROXY-1
<
* CONNECT phase completed
* CONNECT tunnel established, response 200
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /maven2/com/google/guava/guava/25.1-android/guava-25.1-android.jar HTTP/1.1
> Host: repo1.maven.org
> User-Agent: curl/8.8.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:01 --:--:--     0* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< ETag: "b506eaec680c6d92d5f063fa1d57956d"
< Content-Type: application/java-archive
< Last-Modified: Wed, 23 May 2018 17:45:28 GMT
< X-Checksum-MD5: b506eaec680c6d92d5f063fa1d57956d
< X-Checksum-SHA1: bdaab946ca5ad20253502d873ba0c3313d141036
< Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish, HTTPS/1.1 PROXY-1
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Date: Fri, 11 Oct 2024 15:32:45 GMT
< Age: 1482977
< X-Served-By: cache-iad-kcgs7200117-IAD, cache-par-lfpg1960052-PAR
< X-Cache: HIT, HIT
< X-Cache-Hits: 94801, 1
< X-Timer: S1728660766.590888,VS0,VE6
< Content-Length: 2591373
<
* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
{ [32768 bytes data]
* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
  1 2530k    1 32768    0     0    528      0  1:21:47  0:01:01  1:20:46  7065* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
{ [49152 bytes data]
* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
{ [32768 bytes data]

[ ... lots more of this ...]

* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
{ [32768 bytes data]
* schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
{ [32768 bytes data]
100 2530k  100 2530k    0     0  41432      0  0:01:02  0:01:02 --:--:--  799k
* Connection #0 to host our-proxy.xx.xx left intact


I am not sure why you want to use a proxy these days. only I'm not sure why you would want to use a proxy these days. The only benefit would be to intercept and cache things if you have such low internet connection

How about you ask the system admin of that proxy server for help. I would guess your URL is not whitelisted and the proxy server might try to do a virus check.
